# Getting the index entries of a Word document in VBA

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I have a collection of Word docx files in various subfolders. I need to create an index file with links back to the original files. I thought that VBA might be the easiest way to do this. I can find a print a list of every file in my subfolders, but I cannot access the index entry fields.

My first goal was to get a list of every file I need to examine. I adapted the code from http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/ReadFoldersIntoArray.htm to get the file paths.

My second goal is to examine each file and get the index entry fields (the { XE "scissors:running with" } stuff in my documents.

And this is where I am stuck. I can construct a string to the full path name of each file. How do I read the file and get those index entries?

Comment: When you say index do you mean like the table of contents?

Comment: No, I want a specialized index complete with hyperlinks back to the original documents, but I'm saving that headache for later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that using something along the following lines (I haven't tested this exact code, so expect errors)

```
Sub openAndProcess1Document( FullName As String, target As Word.Document )
' FullName is the full path+file name of the .docx
' target is a reference to the document that was the
' ActiveDcoument before you call this routine
' Or you could set up a Range variable and pass that
' So loop through your list of fullnames, calling this Sub
Dim doc as Word.Document
Dim fld as Word.Field
Dim r as Word.Range
Dim strCode as String

Set doc = Documents.Open(FullName)
For each fld in doc.Fields
  if fld.Type = wdFieldIndexEntry then ' It's an XE field
    strCode = fld.Code ' this will look something like 'XE "scissors:running with"'
    ' do whatever you want with strCode here,
    ' e.g. 
    ' Set r = target.Content
    ' r.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    ' r.InsertParagraph
    ' r.InsertAfter strCode
    ' Set r = Nothing
  end if
Next

doc.Close Savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
Set doc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Then you need something like

```
Dim target as Word.Document ' doesn't have to be called "target"! 
Set target = ActiveDocument
For i = 1 to intDocumentCount ' or some such
  Call openAndProcessDocument(strArrayOfDocumentFullNames(i), target)
Next ' i
' optionally...
target.Activate
```

Comment: Thanks. This is close. It doesn't crash, but it doesn't do anything just yet. I am in Word 2007 (probably should have said). According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213727(v=office.12).aspx I think I want wxFieldIndexEntry, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Aha! Further tests showed that documents.Open replaces ActiveDocument, which makes some sort of perverse sense. This code was adding the information about the fields in the local document, not the index document. I saved my index as the active, and I could write to that.

Comment: Yes, it's wdFieldIndexEntry. I have corrected, and made a suggestionabout how to deal with the existing ActiveDocument

Comment: Thanks again. I now have a list of links. I'm off to try the next step of the process.